# A button that linked 2 buttons together with a line (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I had made another new change. Now it can sometimes draw lines between the buttons when I double clicked but it seems that it does not works the way that I intended too. Like I can connect any button when I clicked the 'Add line' button but instead it's kind of buggy. Sometimes it registered my double click and sometimes when I clicked button 1 and 5 and it connects 2 and 3 instead. So how can I do like, it will connect Button 2 and 3 when I only double clicked Button 2 and 3.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

counter = 1
undone = []

numcount = 1

def drag_start(event):
    widget = event.widget
    widget.startX = event.x
    widget.startY = event.y

def drag_motion(event):
    global x, y
    widget = event.widget
    x = widget.winfo_x() - widget.startX + event.x
    y = widget.winfo_y() - widget.startY + event.y
    widget.place(x = x, y = y)

def add_button():
    global btn
    btn = Button(canvas, text = 'Button ' + str(numcount))  
    btn.pack(side = tkinter.TOP, anchor = tkinter.NW)
    btn.bind('<Button-1>', drag_start)
    btn.bind('<B1-Motion>', drag_motion)

def draw_line(event):
    global click_number
    global x1, y1
    if click_number == 0:
        x1 = x
        y1 = y
        click_number = 1
    else:
        x2 = x
        y2 = y
        canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, width = 2, tag = 'line')
        click_number = 0

def add_line():
    btn.bind('<Double-Button-1>', draw_line)

def num():
    global numcount
    numcount += 1
    add_btn.config(text = 'Add Button')

def func(*funcs):
    def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
        for f in funcs:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
    return combined_func

main = Tk()

main.title('Drag and Drop')
main.geometry('500x500')
canvas = Canvas(main, width = 500, height = 500, background = 'white')
canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
click_number = 0

add_btn = Button(main, text = 'Add Button', command = func(add_button, num))
add_btn.place(x = 400, y = 10)

line_btn = Button(main, text = 'Add line', command = add_line)
line_btn.place(x = 400, y = 40)

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: you might need a canvas widget to draw the line. Can I ask you why you want movable buttons? Also, can you add a demonstration of where the lines should be added and how the lines should move around?

Comment: I just want to experiment with it. The lines are behind the button and probably centre of the button and when the button is moving, the lines follow it too. Like one straight line connecting with both of the buttons.